# Changing from client-side pagination to server-side

Tags: angularjs, pagination, client-side, server-side

I am changing from client-side pagination to server-side, due to our large data set requirements. However, I am concerned about the built-in angular filtering that I am using at the moment... since, previously, all the data was present at the client side, filtering was simple. After, I change to server-side pagination... what would be the best way to deal with filtering?

Comment: We use server-side filtering. There're some filter which you can't do in client side.

Comment: If you move pagination to server side, You have to do pre-filtering on server side. By pre-filtering I mean, filtering to get the data. post-filtering would be more of to rearrange the data or searching a specific one in the resultant data set after the filter. So, accordingly you can proceed.